# How to impose a time limit on a whole script in Python

Tags: python, time, scripting, limit

The user is entering a python script in a Java GUI python-editor and can run it from the editor. Is there a way to take the user's script and impose a time limit on the total script?

I'm familiar with how to this with functions / signal.alarm(but I'm on windows & unix Jython) but the only solution I have come up with is to put that script in a method in another script where I use the setTrace() function but that removes the "feature" that the value of global variables in it persist. ie.

```
try:
 i+=1
except NameError:
 i=0
```

The value of 'i' increments by 1 with every execution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [threading.Timer](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html?highlight=timer#timer-objects) to run a function in a separate thread after a specified delay (the max duration you want for your program), and in that function use [`thread.interrupt_main`](http://docs.python.org/library/thread.html#thread.interrupt_main) (note it's in module `thread`, **not** in module `threading`!) to raise a KeyboardInterrupt exception in the main thread.

A more solid approach (in case the script gets wedged into some non-interruptible non-Python code, so that it would ignore keyboard interrupts) is to spawn a "watchdog process" to kill the errant script very forcefully if needed (do that *as well as* the above approach, and a little while later than the delay you use above, to give the script a chance to run its destructors, atexit functions, etc, if at all feasible).

Comment: thanks! I'm not an advanced python user but I'm going to try to get this working.

Comment: ah I'm using Jython 2.1 so thread.interrupt_main() doesn't work!

Comment: @Leonidas, I don't know for sure how a Java or Jython thread can best interrupt (cleanly, i.e., with all finalizers and try/finally's running, etc) the whole process.  What about java.lang.System.exit(1)...?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, but maybe wrap it with Threading or Multiprocessing? Have a timer thread that kills it when it times out.